# Change focus on the infragistics ultra grid?

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I want to change the focus on my grid cell.

Suppose I click on a **cell[1,1]** then I want to set the focus on **cell[1,2]**.

Where `cell[1,1]` means cell of (column 1) and (row 1)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the AfterCellActivate event and write this code

```
void grid_AfterCellActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (grid.ActiveCell != null && 
        grid.ActiveCell.Column.Index == 1 && 
        grid.ActiveCell.Row.Index == 1)
    {
        grid.ActiveCell = grid.Rows[1].Cells[2];

        // And if you want also to automatically 
        // put your cell in edit mode add this line
        grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode);
    }

}
```